# インタフェースの実装について

Tags: java

```java
public interface a{
 default void sample(){
 System.out.print("A");
}
}

public interface b extends a{

}

public interface c implements b{
 @Override
 public void sample();
  a.super.sample();
  System.out.print("java");
}
}
}

public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 a a = new c();
 a.sample();
}
}
```

上記コードについて質問したいのですが、

```java
public interface b extends a{

}
```

`ｂ`クラスは`a`を実装しているのに、`sample()`を実装していないのは、
インタフェースを実装するクラスとして間違えていると思うのですが、コンパイルエラーが出ておらず、疑問におもっております。
`ｂ`クラスで`sample()`を実装しなくても可能か教えて頂きたいです。

インタフェースには以下のようなルールがあります。

1. インタフェースのオブジェクトを生成することはできません。
2. インタフェースを実装したクラスは宣言されているメソッドを実装しなければなりません。
3. インタフェース内で定義した変数は、定数になり変更することができません。

Comment: javaのバージョン(java -version)は何でしょうか？バージョンを明記すると回答がつきやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認してみたのですが、Java8でした

Comment: コンパイルエラーがあります。「public interface c implements b{ @Override public void sample();  a.super.sample();  System.out.print("java");}}}」について①interfaceはclassの間違いではないですか？②public void sample();シグニチャではなく、コードを実装するのでは？a.super.sample();は文法的な意味がわかりません。コンパイルエラーのあるコードについての質問は回答しにくいです。

Comment: `public interface b extends a {}` としているので、「インタフェース `b` はインタフェース `a` を継承する」という意味になります。「インタフェースを実装する(implements)」という意味ではありません。

Answer (score 4):

質問文中のコードを、なるべく意図を保ったままコンパイルエラーを解消したコードが以下になります。

```java
public interface a {
    default void sample() {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
}
```

```java
public interface b extends a {

}
```

```java
public class c implements b {
    @Override
    public void sample() {
        b.super.sample();
        System.out.print("java");
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        a a = new c();
        a.sample();
    }
}
```

実際に想定しているコードは上記したものである、という前提で回答すると、

> `ｂ`クラスは`a`を実装しているのに、`sample()`を実装していないのは、
> インタフェースを実装するクラスとして間違えていると思うのですが、コンパイルエラーが出ておらず、疑問におもっております。

まず、 `b` はクラスでなくインタフェースです。
また、仮に `b` は `a` を実装したクラスだとしても、 `sample()` は `a` インタフェースでデフォルト実装されているため、 `b` での実装は省略できます。

ですので、

> `ｂ`クラスで`sample()`を実装しなくても可能か教えて頂きたいです。

の回答は yes ということになります。

---

> インタフェースを実装したクラスは宣言されているメソッドを実装しなければなりません。

については、Java8で default method が導入されました。
default method によってデフォルトの実装が提供されている場合、実装クラス側での override は必須ではなくなっています。

- [The Java® Language Specification Java SE 8 Edition > Chapter 9. Interfaces > 9.4. Method Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4)

> A default method (snip) provides a default implementation for any class that implements the interface without overriding the method.